# How can I run an executable on files whose name begin with a specific phrase? (Windows 7)

Tags: batch-file, command-line, pdflatex

I'd like to run pdflatex.exe on multiple `.tex` files, all beginning with a certain phrase I'd like to get a prompt for before the process starts.

How can I do that?

The files I want to process are named like this:

```
Chap01S01SS01_Description_Name_Whatever.tex
```

So all in all their names all begin with:

```
Chap01
Chap02
and so forth...
```

**All** the names end on `.tex`.

Obviously the numbers vary for the chapters and sections. This is why I'd like to make it easy for myself with the prompt: if I'd like to just run the files for section 2 in chapter 3, I run those, at some point I'd like to re-generate all the files for chapter 4 and 5... and so forth.

### SOLUTION

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=D:\files\"
SET /p mask="Which .tex-files?"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /a-d "%mask%*.tex" '
 ) DO (
 pdflatex.exe -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape "%%a" any other parameters perhaps containing "%%~na"
 )
POPD

GOTO :EOF
```

Full credit goes to [Magoo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25289551/3181048), I just added the parameters `-interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape` for the use with pdflatex. If you know what "externalization" stands for in regards to TikZ/pgfplots, use it, otherwise **delete** `--shell-escape`.

*BONUS* Just copy the file and write `lualatex.exe` instead of `pdflatex.exe` for huge graphics. Do note your preamble must be organized accordingly though.

Comment: Examples would be good - both of files-to-process and files-to-exclude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET /p mask="select which *.tex files ? "
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /a-d "%mask%*.tex" '
 ) DO (
 ECHO(pdflatex.exe "%%a" any other parameters perhaps containing "%%~na"
)
POPD

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances, or even use a similar `set /p` scheme to input the required directory, if you wish.

Since you haven't stated what the `pdflatex` command line looks like, I can only show pointers.

The required `pdflatex` commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(pdflatex` to `pdflatex` to actually process the files.

Comment: Ok this is so far the best one. Working on it.... are you interested in the final outcome?

Comment: I'm sure someone will be.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a wildcard specification that matches all the files you want, and only those files, processing them is trivial with something like

```
FOR %%f IN (Chap01*) DO ECHO Processing file: %%f
```

So the problem reduces creating a wildcard specification after prompting the user. You can accept user input interactively with `SET /P`, for example:

```
SET chapter=
SET /P chapter=Chapter to process (ENTER for everything)?
REM now %chapter% contains the input, or blank if none was given
```

Putting it all together to get a proof of concept:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET chapter=
SET section=
SET /P chapter=Chapter to process (ENTER for all)?
SET /P section=Section to process (ENTER for all)?

REM We 'll be left-padding the values to two digits with zeroes
SET chapter_spec=??
SET chapter=00%chapter%
SET section=00%section%
IF NOT "%chapter%"=="00" SET chapter_spec=%chapter:~-2%
IF NOT "%section%"=="00" SET section_spec=S%section:~-2%

SET wildcard=Chap%chapter_spec%%section_spec%*.tex
ECHO Files to be processed:
FOR %%f IN (%wildcard%) DO ECHO %%f
```

Comment: That is one good-looking answer. Magoo's looks a bit straightforward for me personally, so I am currently working to implement his/her one. Thank you for your effort. I certainly will try it just for learning.